# How do I remove vertical lines from stem() and combine plot()?

Tags: plot

So I got some sample code.

```
x = linspace(0,1,5);
y = x.^2 + 8*x;
u = [2,1,3,9,3];
figure
axis([0,10,-100,100])
stem(x,u)
plot(x,y)
```

Can someone tell me

1) How do I remove those vertical lines? I just want to make a scatter plot

2) How do i combine the curve $$y = x^2 + 8x$$ and the scatter plot? I am having a hard time finding the correct commands.

3) And what is the equivalent of "axis" for stem?

Answer (score 0):

1. In matlab, apparently there is a command called `scatter` with the same parameters.
2. `hold on` is the command to

figure

```
stem(x,u); hold on;
plot(x,y);
```

3. Axis should be the last thing in the plot